# tcltk2 and external Shiny server

Tags: r, shiny

I'm creating a Shiny web application and I need to be able to produce some messageboxes and listboxes. I've used the solutions from tcltk2 and produced a listbox like in the example here: http://www.sciviews.org/recipes/tcltk/TclTk-listboxes/

This works fine whenever I deploy the app locally on my computer. However, when I try to run it on an external Ubuntu server (not Rstudios Server solution) I receive an error message that the app unexpectedly closed. The JavaScript console doesn't provide much info:

```
 Warning: Unhandled error in observer: [tcl] invalid command name "font".

 observeEvent(input$saveReport)

 shiny-server.js:238 Tue Mar 22 2016 08:46:42 GMT+0100 (Rom, normaltid): 
 Connection closed. Info: {"type":"close","code":1000,"reason":"Normal 
 closure","wasClean":true}
```

I'm not sure what this means and I'm hoping for some guidance.

Comment: i think `tcltk2` not create message on client side. ( cant try but i think if you run your app in intranet localy and visit site from other PC your cant see message on client side). you need shiny message for shiny  ( smth like [1](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/server-to-client-custom-messages.html) or use javascrint messages for it.

Comment: @Batanichek Okay, this was also what I thought, but I would like it confirmed. Unfortunately, Shiny do not provide any solutions to create message- nor inputboxes. Are you aware of any way to accomplish this without having to know JavaScript?

Comment: you can create addition tab in your shiny app with needed inputs and navigate on it when needed( when meesages have to be showed), after submit navigate backward and hide tab ( may be with shinyjs)

Comment: @Batanichek Yes, this was also my goto solution, if nothing else came up. Anyway, thank you for your help. I will probably end up with just creating a new tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `shinyBS` can help you

see

```
#install.packages("shinyBS") if not instaled
library(shinyBS)
bsExample("Modals")
```

It s simular with new tab but shows like pop-up and a bit easy to use.

Comment: This looks nice. I will give it a try! Thank you.